# Spring boot Wiremock jettyWebserver conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jetty, wiremock

My dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        LOMBOK_VERSION = '1.18.22'
        SLF4J_VERSION = '1.7.30'
        SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = "2.6.6"
        SPRING_RETRY_VERSION = "1.3.1"
        JUNIT_JUPITER_VERSION = "5.8.2"
        MOCKITO_JUNIT_JUPITER_VERSION = "4.3.1"
        MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION = "9.4.1.jre11"
        LOGSTASH_LOGBACK_ENCODER_VERSION = "7.2"
        TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION = "1.17.6"
        WIREMOCK_VERSION = "2.27.2"
        TEST_GSON_VERSION = "2.10"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}


repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'xxx'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // As this whole project is a test, I´m including everything as implementation
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:${LOGSTASH_LOGBACK_ENCODER_VERSION}"
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.2.0.jre11'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:${TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:${TESTCONTAINERS_VERSION}"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${TEST_GSON_VERSION}"
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:${WIREMOCK_VERSION}"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${JUNIT_JUPITER_VERSION}"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:${MOCKITO_JUNIT_JUPITER_VERSION}"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.JettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'jettyWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog$Writer
    at app//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
```

i got this error when i added the `WIremock` dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the wiremock version to `3.0.0-beta-2`